# How/can I do this in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, database-design

So I have 1 table

```
CREATE TABLE Versions (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    title NVARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and another table

```
CREATE TABLE Questions (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    subsection_id INT NOT NULL,
    qtext NVARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
    version_id INT NOT NULL,
    viewtype INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (subsection_id) REFERENCES Subsections(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (version_id) REFERENCES Versions(id)
);
```

a visual representation of which is like

```
--                                            Questions
-- ============================================================================================================================
--   id  |                 qtext                                              |  subsection_id  |  version_id   |    viewtype
-- =============================================================================================================================
--    1  | 'Does Hillary Clinton look good in orange?'                        |      1          |       1       |        1
--    2  | 'How many prime numbers are there?'                                |      1          |       1       |        1
--    3  | 'What do I suck at writing SQL?'                                   |      1          |       1       |        1
--    4  | 'Would Jon Skeet beat Mark Zuckerberg in a programming contest?'   |      1          |       1       |        1
```

What I need is a procedure that both inserts a new row to the `Versions` table  and adds to the `Questions` table all its current rows with appropriately incremented `id`s and `version_id`s equal to that of the version that was just created.

Example:

If `Versions` goes from

```
id | title 
-----------
 1 | "V1" 
 2 | "V2"
```

then `Questions` goes to

```
--                                            Questions
-- ============================================================================================================================
--   id  |                 qtext                                              |  subsection_id  |  version_id   |    viewtype
-- =============================================================================================================================
--    1  | 'Does Hillary Clinton look good in orange?'                        |      1          |       1       |        1
--    2  | 'How many prime numbers are there?'                                |      1          |       1       |        1
--    3  | 'What do I suck at writing SQL?'                                   |      1          |       1       |        1
--    4  | 'Would Jon Skeet beat Mark Zuckerberg in a programming contest?'   |      1          |       1       |        1
--    5  | 'Does Hillary Clinton look good in orange?'                        |      1          |       2       |        1
--    6  | 'How many prime numbers are there?'                                |      1          |       2       |        1
--    7  | 'What do I suck at writing SQL?'                                   |      1          |       2       |        1
--    8  | 'Would Jon Skeet beat Mark Zuckerberg in a programming contest?'   |      1          |       2       |        1
```

Best attempt with my limited database skills:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OntoNewVersion
    @new_title NVARCHAR(100) 
AS  
    INSERT INTO Versions (title) VALUES (@new_title)
    SET @versid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    SET @qrows = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Questions; -- this is wrong, I know
    SET @i = 1;
    WHILE @i <= @qrows
        BEGIN
            SET @thisq = SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE id=@i
            INSERT INTO Questions (qtext,subsection_id,version_id,viewtype) VALUES (@thisq.qtext,@thisq.subsection_id,@versid,@thisq.viewtype);
        END
```

Is that close to being correct? What needs changed? Is there an overall better way to do this?

Comment: That isn't going to work. In fact, you don't need a loop here at all. You should look at using OUTPUT. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: Please do have a look at my answer

Comment: Why are you creating multiple copies of the questions? Seems you have some normalization problems here.

Comment: @SeanLange No. I don't want to go into detail about the business logic, but basically this procedure is the equivalent of "move the questions on to a new version initialized as the old questions, and keep the old questions stored for reporting purposes"

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Then you need to determine which set of questions you want to copy. the way you have it coded it will exponentially increase the amount of questions. The first time you run this with 4 questions you will have 8, next time it will be 16 etc...unless you include a where clause to limit the questions to a certain group.

Comment: @SeanLange Good point ....

Comment: @SeanLange I made the insertion statement `SELECT qtext, subsection_id,@versid,viewtype FROM Questions WHERE id=(@versid - 1)`. Is that right?

Comment: Assuming you are using the code posted in the accepted answer then that would get you the questions from the current version which I think is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OntoNewVersion
    @new_title NVARCHAR(100) 
AS 
BEGIN 
 BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
    DECLARE @versid INT
    INSERT INTO Versions (title) VALUES (@new_title)
    SET @versid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()


    INSERT INTO Questions 
        (qtext,subsection_id,version_id,viewtype)  
    SELECT qtext, subsection_id,@versid,viewtype 
    FROM Questions  
  COMMIT TRANSACTION T1
 END TRY

 BEGIN CATCH
  IF(@@TRANCOUNT>0)
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION T1
    END
  ;THROW    
 END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Why would you recommend using MAX(Id) instead of what you posted? What you posted is the correct way to do this. Using MAX(Id) is prone to race conditions and concurrency. It is not a good way to do this.

Comment: This is purely because of an unrelated personal experience, a failed transaction cause my identity value to still be incremented and hold a false value which did not actually exists.

Comment: Huh??? SCOPE_IDENTITY will return the last identity value from within the current scope. If the insert fails the value would still be returned but the row did not get inserted. The way to deal with that is to put the whole thing inside a transaction. That way if the insert to Versions fails, the insert to Questions would also get rolled back.

Comment: @SeanLange you are correct! In the case like this question `SCOPE_IDENTITY` would be way to do

Comment: Add a transaction and a TRY/CATCH and this is rock solid.

Comment: Are yo sure that last `END` isn't unnecessary or a mistake?

Comment: If you can help me figure out the `Must declare the scalar variable "@versid".` I'm currently getting then you'll get best answer :)

Comment: @SubparWebDev Stupid me! Missed the declaration. Updated!